# Pivot Matrix for Row Permutations in LU decomposition (C++/CUDA)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, programming, lu-decomposition

I'm trying to implement some determinant routines for some CUDA C++ code that I'm writing. The only issue is, my code is returning nan's and inf's! It turns out that it's my pivoting routine that's bad.

Right now, my overall approach has been ripped straight from rosetta code's C implementation (without those awful macros). But it seems like their pivoting routine isn't robust enough for my needs.

Right now, my pivoting routine will take a column, start at the row corresponding to the column index and then search for the column's largest element below the current row and only swap if a larger value is found.

This is far too naive in practice. Is there a more robust pivoting algorithm I can/should be using?

Here's a link to the source code test: https://github.com/LeonineKing1199/cuda-stuff/blob/master/tests/matrix-tests.cu#L182

If you look at that matrix, that's the properly permuted one. In my actual data,  the rows of the matrix can be in any order! I just needed a static test to make sure it would eventually work. So, what kind of pivoting algorithm would I need to help me produce that same matrix assuming the rows were permuted in any order?

Sorry if I haven't given enough information. My main matrix class is here: https://github.com/LeonineKing1199/cuda-stuff/blob/master/include/math/matrix.hpp

Comment: Two questions 1) Can we have an idea of the size $n$ of your matrices ? Are you aware that numerical computation of determinants, say when $n$ is above some hundreds is very instable and prone for different reasons (bad condition number in particular) to be either too large (say $> 10^{100}$) or too small. 2) And above all, why do you need determinants ? In most cases, numerical analysts bypass computing determinants (unless it is very small determinants) for the reason I have said.

Comment: So, my code is attempting to calculate tetrahedralizations of 3d point sets. This means that at the very most, all I would ever need is a 5x5 matrix determinant when calculating if a point in the triangulated set is contained in the circumsphere of any tetrahedron in the mesh.

Comment: Then, in my opinion, there is nothing better (and simpler !) than to enter explicit formulas (one for each case, 2,3,4,5) with some factorizations to improve the efficiency.

Comment: That's awesome that you say that. I got frustrated the other night and wound up just implementing simple brute-force methods for determinants. I'm happy that you suggested the same thing as it makes me feel somewhat validated.